# LLDB redirect inferior stdout

Tags: macos, lldb

I'm using LLDB with the latest OS X toolchain (`lldb --version` says `lldb-340.4.110`).

I tried to debug executable which produces lots of output into stdout.
Previously it was possible to suppress output by redirecting it, e.g. to `/dev/null`.

But after latest OS X toolchain update it has started producing the following error:

```
(lldb) run >/dev/null
error: invalid JSON
```

Has something changed in LLDB in that area? Like adding some syntax for specifying stdin/stdout/stderr redirects. Can't find any clue in LLDB docs or mailing lists. Also I can suppose it is Apple-specific LLDB bug.

**P.S.**

I know that my problem can be temporary solved by running:
`sudo lldb -w -n <executable>` in separate terminal window, which will tell LLDB to wait for new process with the given name and then attach to that process. In that case I can run my executable in another terminal window with `stdin` redirected to `/dev/null`.

But I feel highly uncomfortable with that workflow, because stdout redirect just works in GDB on my Linux machine. Breaking the habits is always uncomfortable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(lldb) process launch -o /dev/null -- <OTHER ARGUMENTS>
```

will do what you want.  You can also make an alias to do this:

```
(lldb) command alias silent-run process launch -o /dev/null --
```

then:

```
(lldb) silent-run a b c
```

will run your program, redirect stdout to /dev/null, and pass a, b and c as arguments.

Comment: The long form of `-o` seems to be `--stdout`. There are also `--stderr` and `--stdin` options.